# How to configure the test flow using xunit

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

I'm new xunit and want to configure the test flow using xunit. For example, there are several test methods A, B, C, D, and I want to ran them in several ways:
1. Run them in a specific order B, A, C, D
2. Warp A, B, C to a test list, they can be ran in random order.
etc...

I used MSTest before and found these can be set by modifying the config file, I want to know in xunit, how should I implement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through following links:

1. http://blog.athico.com/2011/10/cookbook-how-to-test-rules-using-xunit.html
2. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t584773-unit-testing-vhdl-using-xunit.html